# AngularJS: Binding not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, ng-show

I have a login page that displays inside my index.html page. The index.html page has control over a navigation bar that I don't want to show up until the user has successfully logged in. After they login however, the navigation bar ng-show attribute doesn't get updated as I have it in code. Here is the code to illustrate:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-controller="loginController" ng-show={{valid}}>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse-links">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="addUser" class="addUser" >Add User</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="listUser" class="mdUser">Modify User</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="login" class="mdUser">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Inside my controller looks like this:

```
$scope.valid = false;
function login() {
    AuthenticationService.Login(vm.user.username, vm.user.password, function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(response.token.UserName, response.token.TokenId);
            $scope.valid = true;
            $location.path('/');
            } else {
                //FlashService.Error(response.message);
                vm.error = response.message;
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            }
    ....
    )};
}
```

These is a crude copying and pasting of the code that only contains what I believe is necessary for the current issue.

I can manually change the declaration to true or false and have the navigation bar act correctly. Otherwise, the navigation bar doesn't show up after a valid login attempt, and when I check the html in the console after the login, the ng-show method still shows as false.

**QUESTION:** Why isn't the valid binding correctly to change after it is reassigned in my success function?

Comment: What is your authenticationService? Sidenote, ng-show does not need {{}}. `ng-show="valid"` is perfectly fine

Comment: Its a custom service I have to authenticate with our backend. Done testing on that and its working how it should..shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `AuthenticationService` doesn't pump the digest loop, Angular will not update its bindings because it won't know that something has changed.

Try wrapping the body of your `.Login` callback in a [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

Also, you're navigating away from this view immediately after authenticating the user so the scope where you set `$scope.valid = true;` is gone.

You can try setting a flag on the root scope like: `$rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;` and bind against that since the rootscope is kept around for the life of the application.

You're best option is to store the authentication state in your service and binding against that instead. Since services are singletons, that state will be preserved between views as well.

Comment: How do I make the ng-show look for the rootscope.valid instead of its local "valid"? Never mind just needed a little research

Comment: For what you're trying to do you may be better served using ui-router and doing a parent view for your app chrome. That way you can easily have a login route that isn't parented by the chrome and there's no header, because, well there's no header. Then every view (your protected views) would be parented by that view. All you have to do is put an `<ng-view/>` in the parent view where the contents of the child view is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `{{ }}` from ng-show.  That is one issue with your code.

```
ng-show="valid"
```

And check this out for some more info:

http://jaketrent.com/post/when-to-use-curlies-in-angular-directives/

Comment: Good to know, but I changed it and it still isn't binding

Comment: Did you see joshperry's answer?  You might have a few problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-controller="loginController" ng-show={{valid}}>
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-controller="loginController" ng-show="valid">
```